# SASS: make a color closer to white?

Tags: css, sass, opacity

Is there a color function in SASS that essentially mixes a given color with white? `lightness` doesn't work because it makes the color look more saturated. `saturation` doesn't work because it can make the color darker. A combination of `lightness` and `saturation` works, but I have to manually tune it to get the right balance.

In other words, imagine having an element over a white background. Then, you can change the element's opacity to make it closer to white. Is there something like this in SASS?

Comment: Couldn't you do `adjust-color($color, $red: -40, $green: -40, $blue: -40)`?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/tint-shade-functions/ ? `mix(white, $color, $percentage)`